# List all Team Drives for an user with app script or Drive api v3

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I need to list all Team Drives for an user with app script, but I don't know how to make this.
I searched in the Drive API documentation, but I found nothing to resolve my problem.

Someone to help me ?
Thanks

Comment: Hi all,

I've resolved my problem with OAuth2 library and use "headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + oauth2Service.getAccessToken()}" in place of ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()

Thanks for all for your help

Answer (score 0):

I have a function which returns the list of Team Drives.  I pulled this into my notes some time ago, and no longer can give credit to where it originally came from (it may have come from Google's own documentation).  I apologize if the format is bad -- I am new to stackoverflow and can't figure out how to format it to its liking:

```html
/**
 * Purpose: Return a list of all Team Drive names
 */
function getGoogleTeamDrives() {
  try {
    var teamDrives = {},
        baseUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/teamdrives",
        token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
        params = {
          pageSize: 10,
          fields: "nextPageToken,teamDrives(id,name)"
        };
    do {
      var queryString = Object.keys(params).map(function(p) {
        return [encodeURIComponent(p), encodeURIComponent(params[p])].join("=");
      }).join("&amp;");
      var apiUrl = baseUrl + "?" + queryString;
      var response = JSON.parse(
        UrlFetchApp.fetch( apiUrl, {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token}
        }).getContentText());
      response.teamDrives.forEach(function(teamDrive) {
        teamDrives[teamDrive.id] = teamDrive.name;
        //Logger.log('Team Drive: ' + teamDrive.name);
      })
      params.pageToken = response.nextPageToken;
    } while (params.pageToken);
    return teamDrives;
  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f.toString());
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi Craig, thanks for your answer. I saw this code yesterday by searching the Internet. The problem is that it lists the TDs for the connected user. I would like to be able to do it as admin for several users.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I tend to giving a comment, however, I don't have enough rep.
I have not tested this one, so if it can not work, just ignore my answer.

In the code above at the params object add: useDomainAdminAccess : true

Since I am not the G suite Admin, so I am not sure what the result would be.

You can always use "Try the api" to test your calling: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/teamdrives/get

Good luck!